# Why does std::any_cast give segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use std::any in std::map. The key will be string but value will be std::string, double and std::vector. To start using it I just tried a simple example, but I get run time error saying `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

```
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, std::any> kval;

template<typename T>
T GetVal(const std::string& key){
  if(kval.find(key) == kval.end()){
    std::cerr << "There is no key : " << key << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  std::any& ref =  kval[key];

  return *std::any_cast<T>(&ref);
}

int main(){
  // string
  kval["one"] = "val";
  // decial
  kval["two"] =  3.9;
  // vector
  std::vector<double> tmp;
  kval["three"] =  tmp;

  std::any tmp1 = GetVal<std::string>("one");

}
```

Compiled using : 
g++ -g -std=c++17 test_vector_any.cpp

Comment: What type is `"..."`. Hint: it's not `std::string`. `std::any` requires the *exact* type. No conversions allowed.

Comment: Consider checking the return value of the any_cast before dereferencing it.

Comment: How can I check checking the return value of the any_cast ?

Comment: Check your return value like:  `std::any& ref =  kval[key]; auto result = std::any_cast<T>(&ref); if (result == nullptr) { std::cerr << "There is no value for key : " << key << std::endl; exit(1); }`

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ok now I get it. I was placing char char * instead of std::string. Thanks for leading me to the answer rather then spoon feeding me guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) is used with a pointer to `std::any`, the return type is a pointer. That pointer needs to be checked against `nullptr` to validate that the type contained in the `std::any` is, indeed, of the type that you expect. If it is a `nullptr`, then dereferencing it will cause undefined behavior; usually the Segmentation Fault that you're observing.

You have two options. Either you can throw the `std::bad_any_cast` exception that normally happens when you use the non-pointer version of `std::any_cast` (and catch it in the calling code), or you can manually check for the pointer yourself and handle it.

```
//Manual Checking
template<typename T>
T GetVal(const std::string& key){
    if(auto it = kval.find(key); it != kval.end()){
        std::any& ref = it->second;
        T * ptr = std::any_cast<T>(&ref);
        if(ptr)
            return *ptr;
        else
            //or exit(1);
            throw std::runtime_error("Type did not match expected type");
    } else {
        std::cerr << "There is no key : " << key << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

//Checking using built in exceptions
template<typename T>
T GetVal(const std::string& key){
    if(auto it = kval.find(key); it != kval.end()){
        std::any& ref = it->second;
        return std::any_cast<T>(ref); //Will throw std::bad_any_cast if the type doesn't match
    } else {
        std::cerr << "There is no key : " << key << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```